# xcode interface builder objects

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to create a form for an iphone app. I'm using interface builder to create the fields. I need the equivalent of a select drop down menu. The documentation says to use a pop-up button, but I can't find the darn thing. Where the heck is it??

Also, what about checkboxes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a drop-down menu use `UIPickerView` named just "Picker View" in IB. Another option although much harder to implement is a collapsible UITableView.

There are no checkboxes provided by default, so usually it is just an image, that changes when you click it. Or you can use a `UISwitch` named just "Switch" in IB

Comment: I assumed it was Picker View, but I don't see how to make it look like a single selection which expands when you click on the arrows at the edge.